# Android RecyclerView strange item size

Tags: android, xml, android-recyclerview

Every Item in my RecyclerView has more free space under the text than above the text. Here is what i mean: 
[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iuD2r.png)
[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/exjYq.png)

Here is my XML code of the items:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
    >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/textViewItem" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Why does it do that?

kinda SOLUTION: remove paddingBottom, put paddingTop to 10dp - works only for a fixed text size.

Comment: Where do you update text in your text view

Comment: Your solution won't work as soon as you add any other element to your list row layout, change <code>TextView</code> text size or simply change the height of the row to some fixed value. I post the answer below with explanation how to avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

try put paddingbottom only remove the top.

Comment: That made it even worse. But now i deleted paddingBottom and put paddingTop to 10dp and it's perfect. So thank you :D

Comment: it happens because the the first item has padding bottom then the next item has padding top so it makes it bigger space

Answer (score 0):

This is because you use `LinearLayout` as parent container, where elements don't center itself. If you want to center them vertically or horizontally, use `RelativeLayout` as a parent container and `android:layout_centerHorizontal`, `android:layout_centerVertical` or `android:layout_centerInParent` attributes for child views.

Comment: Even if i set android:layout_centerVertical="true", it doesn't work. Still missplaced...

Comment: @DaveLillo Have you replaced LinearLayout with RelativeLayout?

Comment: @Ales Bernikov yes, i did